# Site refresh time is long in laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, refresh

Hello and do not be tired!!

My admin panel pages are hard to load...It takes 15 seconds for the pages to load!!

The problem is with my routes!!!

Because when I define the path as follows, the pages load quickly :

```
Route::get('users/index', function () {

    return view('admin.index');

});
```

But the route I have defined is as follows :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth' , 'InfoFolder' , 'verified' , 'Roles'] , 'prefix' => 'users/'] , function(){

    Route::get('{url}', [UrlController::class , 'urlpanel'])->name('users_url');
   

});
```

And the control I have defined :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UrlController extends Controller
{

    //
    public function urlpanel($url ){

        $admin = "admin";
        $pages = "admin.pages";
        $charts = "admin.pages.charts";
        $examples = "admin.pages.examples";
        $forms = "admin.pages.forms";
        $mailbox = "admin.pages.mailbox";
        $tables = "admin.pages.tables";
        $UI = "admin.pages.UI";

        $link_panel = [

            'index' => "$admin.index",
            'list_users' => "$admin.list_users",
            'index3' => "$admin.index3",
            'calendar' => "$pages.calendar",
            'widgets' => "$pages.widgets",
            'chartjs' => "$charts.chartjs",
            'flot' => "$charts.flot",
            'inline' => "$charts.inline",
            '404' => "$examples.404",
            '500' => "$examples.500",
            'blank' => "$examples.blank",
            'invoice-print' => "$examples.invoice-print",
            'invoice' => "$examples.invoice",
            'lockscreen' => "$examples.lockscreen",
            'login' => "$examples.login",
            'profile' => "$examples.profile",
            'register' => "$examples.register",
            'product_add' => "$forms.product_add",
            'editors' => "$forms.editors",
            'general' => "$forms.general",
            'compose' => "$mailbox.compose",
            'mailbox' => "$mailbox.mailbox",
            'read-mail' => "$mailbox.read-mail",
            'data' => "$tables.data",
            'simple' => "$tables.simple",
            'buttons' => "$UI.buttons",
            'general' => "$UI.general",
            'icons' => "$UI.icons",
            'sliders' => "$UI.sliders",

        ];


        if(!in_array($link_panel[$url] , $link_panel)){
            return abort(404);
        }

        return view($link_panel[$url]);


    }


}
```

How can I increase the loading speed of my website?

The project has been uploaded to Localhost

:)

Comment: Hasn't this been posted in a similar form recently? Have you tried not using _one_ route for all but different routes for different purposes?

Comment: I did not understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the middlewares you are using. Maybe in one of the middlewares there is some time consuming action.

Comment: No ...... The speed changes after turning the Apache off and on once

Comment: then probably you have a problem on the server side, try asking the support of your host

Comment: The project has been uploaded to Localhost 